# Как убрать прокрутку у ListView

Tags: xml, android-studio, listview, android-sdk

В процессе разработки приложения для введения списка покупок столкнулся с неприятной проблемой.
Есть `LinearLayout` в нем два `ListView`, так вот, мне нужно сделать чтобы прокручивались не `ListView`, а `LinearLayout`  вместе с контентом из `ListView`.
Пробовал засунуть `LinearLayout` в `ScrollView`, в итоге отображался лишь первый элемент каждого `ListView`.

```
    ` <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
    <ListView
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:id="@+id/items2"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/itemok"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/padding_small"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:id="@+id/items"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/padding_small"/>

</LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте назначить такой обработчик вашему `listView`

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true; //Указывает, что это было обработано вами и больше не будет перенаправлено
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338185/how-to-get-a-non-scrollable-listview) и таких тем в интернете очень много